# Replacing special characters and double spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a string, `'AMERICAN:BEER~ INVENTIONS  CHOCOLATE-FEVER'`.

We are trying to remove special characters and replace that with a space and later checking if we have created any double spaces, and we try to replace the double spaces with a single space.

So, if we remove the special characters, and we remove the double spaces, we are left with `'AMERICAN BEER INVENTIONS CHOCOLATE FEVER'`.

The problem here is, we have unintentionally removed, the default double space between `'INVENTIONS  CHOCOLATE'`.

How can we avoid this?

My current approach:

1. Remove special characters:

   ```
    UPDATE xxxx.xxxxx
    SET xxxx = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(xxxx, '<', ' '), '>', ' '), '(', ' '), ')', ' '), ':', ' '), '#', ' '), '~', ' ')  
    WHERE xxxx LIKE '%[<>:()#~]%';
   ```
2. Pass the column in a function to remove double spaces:

   ```
   SET @str = TRIM(@str);  

   WHILE CHARINDEX('  ', @str) > 0  
    SET @str = REPLACE(@str, '  ', ' ');
   ```

Comment: SQL Server's T-SQL has relatively poor string processing functionality. Is there a reason you're trying to do this in the database rather than preventing the duff data from being inserted in the first place via a more capable language?

Comment: Have you considered normalising your design to start with? Then you don't have a problem, as each distinct value is on its own row. The design is the real route of the problem here.

Comment: One way to do this is to replace double spaces with either a character, or a combination of characters that you know will never appear in your data, then perform your processing, then convert that character/series of characters back into a double space.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work for you?

Using *translate* to convert to a single character, then remove additional spaces and finally replace the unwanted character:

```
declare @s varchar(50) = 'AMERICAN:BEER ~ INVENTIONS  CHOCOLATE-FEVER'
select Replace(Replace(Replace(Translate(@s, '<>:()~-','#######'), '# ', '#'), ' #', '#'), '#', ' ');
```

Result
`AMERICAN BEER INVENTIONS  CHOCOLATE FEVER`